# Breaking a bitmask down in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, bit

I have an old database design I'm working with that uses bitmasks.  I have table that houses email addresses and a bitmask based on another table, and have been tasked with writing a SQL query which "breaks down" these bit masks.  Generally, this data is viewed in a different manner, where we utilize a bitwise & to determine if the bitmask is valid, but not the case this time...

In a simplified version of my data, I have 2 fields like so.

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Email          |     bitMask      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     test@test.com   |        3         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    test2@test.com   |        9         |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

The output I'm ultimately looking for would show what "powers of 2", or what "bits" it took to get to the bitmask, so I can cross-reference the mask values in another table.  So my sample output is something like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Email          |     value        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     test@test.com   |        2         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     test@test.com   |        1         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    test2@test.com   |        8         |
|---------------------|------------------| 
|    test2@test.com   |        1         |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

This is the opposite way I'm used to dealing with bitmasks.  If anyone knows how to go about writing this query, any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&` (bitwise AND operator), with `0xFFFFFFFE` to get the *powers of 2* part and with `1` to get the 1st binary digit (`0` or `1`):

```
select [Email], [bitMask] & 0xFFFFFFFE [value]
from tablename  
union all
select [Email], [bitMask] & 1
from tablename  
order by [Email], [value] desc
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=566fbe602c268af181d3317b74d0c63c).
Results:

```
> Email          | value
> :------------- | ----:
> test@test.com  |     2
> test@test.com  |     1
> test2@test.com |     8
> test2@test.com |     1
```